# Im looking ROS distro for BeagleBone Black Rev.C

Tags: ros-lunar, rplidar, ros-kinetic, ros-hydro, beaglebone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone.

For my robotic project im looking distro of ROS compatible with BeagleBone Black RevC. dev. platform. Unfortunatelly when I try install standard Kinetic distro for Debian from here:
http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Debian
the system takes me this:

```
E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-desktop-full
```

What is going on? Im used wrong version of Debian or something else? Or maybe someone had similar problem with BeagleBone Black?
Could someone help me to find solution of this problem? I would like to use this platform with RPlidarA1 in my robot project bud I can't do anything without ROS.

My kernel and system:

```
Linux beaglebone 4.4.113-ti-r147 #1 SMP Tue Feb 20 20:44:47 UTC 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I think thats the Debian Jessie 8.10 so ROS should been works without problems?

Thanks for help.
Greetings Tom

```
root@beaglebone:~# apt-get update && sudo dpkg -l ros-kinetic*
Hit http://repos.rcn-ee.com jessie InRelease
Ign http://deb.debian.org jessie InRelease
Hit http://packages.ros.org trusty InRelease
Hit https://deb.nodesource.com jessie InRelease
Hit http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease
Hit http://deb.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease
Hit http://deb.debian.org jessie Release.gpg
Get:1 http://repos.rcn-ee.com jessie/main armhf Packages [578 kB]
Hit http://deb.debian.org jessie Release
Get:2 http://packages.ros.org trusty/main armhf Packages [750 kB]
Get:3 https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main armhf Packages [1,003 B]
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates/main armhf Packages [23.1 kB]
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates/contrib armhf Packages [20 B]
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates/non-free armhf Packages [450 B]
Get:7 http://deb.debian.org jessie/updates/main armhf Packages [614 kB]
Get:8 http://deb.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib armhf Packages [994 B]
Get:9 http://deb.debian.org jessie/updates/non-free armhf Packages [20 B]
Get:10 http://deb.debian.org jessie/main armhf Packages [8,864 kB]
Get:11 http://deb.debian.org jessie/contrib armhf Packages [44.3 kB]
Get:12 http://deb.debian.org jessie/non-free armhf Packages [74.9 kB]
Fetched 11.0 MB in 21s (512 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
dpkg-query: no packages found matching ros-kinetic*
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285963/im-looking-ros-distro-for-beaglebone-black-rev.c/) by [tomek242](https://answers.ros.org/users/34233/tomek242/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-03-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2018-03-20**:
Please edit your message and add the output of the following commands: `sudo apt-get update && sudo dpkg -l ros-kinetic*` and `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list`

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2018-03-20**:
Nevermind, I thought the BeagleBone had a 64 bit CPU, I'll answer to your question now

**Comment by [tomek242](https://answers.ros.org/users/34233/tomek242/) on 2018-03-20**:
So I can't use ROS for this platform?

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2018-03-20**:
You can, take a look at my answer, especially the last part!

**Comment by [tomek242](https://answers.ros.org/users/34233/tomek242/) on 2018-03-20**:
I just wrote another question before I saw Your answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I am correct the BeagleBone Rev C has a `AM335x 1GHz ARM® Cortex-A8` CPU. This is a 32 bits CPU.
If you take a look at what Debian packages are compiled on the top of the tutorial, you'll see that there is only `amd64` and `arm64`

The BeagleBone CPU falls into the `armhf` (ARM Hard-Float) category, there is no binary package available for your platform on Debian.

You have two choices:

- Compile from source (there is a link
  for that at the top of the tutorial
  you mention)
- Use Ubuntu on your
  BeagleBone, binaries are provided for
  `armhf` CPUs platform on Ubuntu

---

Originally posted by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) with karma: 1505 on 2018-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tomek242](https://answers.ros.org/users/34233/tomek242/) on 2018-03-20**:
Yeah I see this diffirent at now. Ok thanks anyway for help.